# SQL SERVER 2012 datatype error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL server 2012 and while practicing I noticed an error which I couldn't rectify.

I created a table with primary key and another table having its reference. Ref table:

```
create table emp
(
   empno integer not null,
   ename varchar(10),
   job varchar(9),
   mgr varchar(10),
   hiredate date,
   sal decimal(7,2),
   comm decimal(12,3),
   deptno integer references dept(deptno)
)
```

Tried to insert values using

```
insert into emp values(100,'Sachin','IT','Srikanth','10-10-2009',
  50000.00,500.00,1)
```

But am getting the following error.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

Also if I change the data type of COMM to `decimal`, the error disappears.

Comment: I couldn't get this insert statement to fail. Are you sure this is exactly the one that fails?

Comment: No Error in query, execute fine in my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query  `[decimal(7,2)]` data types are the issue.

The `(7,2)` tells you that the number can have a precision of 7 digits total, with 2 digits being reserved for the decimal portion.

Thus, you only have 4 digit available to store values like **5000.00 is valid** , and **500000.00 which causes the overflow**.

Comment: There is no value 500000.00 in the question. 50000.00 is there, but it fits into 7,2 just fine.

Comment: Yes. Agree.. But this scenario possible to arithmetic overflow exception throws..

Comment: I suspect you're right, and that the OP didn't actually reveal the true statement that is causing the error, but your answer still implies that there is an invalid value in the question (that perhaps you read incorrectly), which there isn't...